# Identifying CRC-16 algorithm used

Tags: crc, crc16

I'm trying to communicate with a device over a serial communication protocol and having some trouble finding out about which checksum/crc algorithm that is used for the last 2 bytes of the messages. I've tried several CRC16 algorithms in various online crc utilities, like:
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html
http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html

I've also tried reverse engineering, with the help of REVENG software, but it only gives some occasional random hits (depending on which of the examples from the captured messages I try together), that does not seem to be a correct algorithm that matches all examples.

I have not found any documentation of the device, which can indicate the CRC16 algorithm used or if its some other variant like the lowest bytes of a CRC32.

Below are 2 types of messages each with some different examples and variations. The first 4 bytes of the message tells the renaming number of bytes of the message. Most probably these 4 first bytes should not be included in the CRC calculation, but that is just a guess. What I believe is a 16 wide CRC is the last 2 bytes of each message.

**Message type 1 (examples):**

0000000908100300180a4621a8

0000000901100300180a463a11

0000000909100300180a461f26

0000000902100300180a4649f9

000000090a100300180a466cce

0000000903100300180a46fb58

000000090b100300180a46de6f

**Message type 2 (examples):**

0000001f09131900180a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a7be0

0000001f0913190018141414141414141414141414141414141414141414141414f3a5

0000001f09131900181e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e1e3d38

0000001f0913190018282828282828282828282828282828282828282828282828e82f

0000001f09131900183232323232323232323232323232323232323232323232321762

0000001f001319001814ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff3d16

0000001f00131900181effffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff2e93

0000001f001319001828ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff3438

0000001f00131900185fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffac2b

Anyone out there with some knowledge about CRC that can point me in the right direction to figure this out?

Comment: If this is a CRC, you can XOR two of the test messages, to end up with a mostly zero message, which might help, but Mark Adler answered that it doesn't seem to be a CRC. For example, XOR on the first two messages results in 00000000090000000000001bb9, second two 00000000080000000000002537, then XOR'ing both of those 00000000010000000000003e8e .

Answer (score 0):

It's not a CRC-16. I ran a simple brute-force search.

Comment: Mark, Any other clue of what the algorithm for these 2 bytes can be? Or things you can recommend to test? I've verified that the values of these two bytes reoccur (are identical) when the rest bytes of the message is the same, but I can't see any logic in how they change even if there are just minor changes in the byte structure.

Comment: As best as I can tell from the limited samples, it is a linear function over GF(2), which means each bit in the check value is an exclusive-or of a specific subset of the bits in the message, for a given length message. This could be verified with hundreds, or better, thousands of examples.

Comment: It's better to have different lengths, but at least you can get started with a bunch of the same length.

Comment: I've gathered 1200 samples of message type 2. They can be found here: http://dpaste.com/0DSMZJV or for the same messages but with whitespce inside: http://dpaste.com/2BAB799. I've tried to get messages that could point in some direction where only some bytes are changing and I can see some intresseting things when looking on messages where just the 2 last bytes Changes, this gives small changes to the 2 checksum bytes. See some examples of this below. But I cannot really see the full pattern here, Any Idea?

Comment: Turns out it's not a linear function of GF(2). So not a simple set of ands / shifts / exclusive-ors.

Comment: Mark, thanks for you're answer. So no idea or thought then how to get further on this?

Comment: Nope. I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Some more messages where only one or two of the last "data" bytes are varying that show some sort of more logical behaviour on the last 2 checksum bytes, but still no clear view of how the algorithm is constructed for the calculation.
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Full set of 1200 messages at: http://dpaste.com/0DSMZJV